# phpunit command not working in lumen 5.6 running on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: php, ubuntu, lumen, lampp

Only Two Files in the tests directory,
TestCase.php and ExampleTest.php

Below is the source code(It's a completely new Lumen installation, not added any new tests actually, just the default test file that comes with it):

```
<?php

use Laravel\Lumen\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;
use Laravel\Lumen\Testing\DatabaseTransactions;

class ExampleTest extends TestCase
{
/**
 * A basic test example.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function testExample()
{
    $this->get('/');

    $this->assertEquals(
        $this->app->version(), $this->response->getContent()
    );
}
}
```

I keep getting Error

```
In Test.php line 100:

Neither "Application Test Suite.php" nor "Application Test Suite.php" could be opened.
```

Screenshot
[image]

All composer needed packages have been installed. 
I am using lampp installation with the latest php 7.2 version in ubuntu 16.04 OS.

What could be the issue?
I cannot even seem to find the Test.php file, that the error indicates.

Comment: can u share your code somewhere??

Comment: I just did. its a new lumen installation  @WilliamFrancisGomes, can't seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 2):

The issue was the version of phpunit that comes with the Latest Lampp I installed is

```
PHPUnit 3.6.0 by Sebastian Bergmann.version 3.6.0
```

located at /opt/lampp/bin/phpunit

which was part of the same installation that had the latest php 7.2.1 version

But the recommended version was

```
PHPUnit 7.0.1 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
```

when I tried running ./vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit from the root of the lumen application it worked!!.

So I had to create alias phpunit="/opt/lampp/..../vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit" to make it easier to call phpunit test

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your ExampleTest.php file doesn't seem to be the problem. Check out the file Test.php on line 100. Even though it's a new project you have added or changed the Test file and that is causing your trouble for now.